# How to select the preceding-sibling inside a for each loop?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>
            <name>Empire Burlesque1 </name>
        </title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>
            <name>Empire Burlesque 2</name>
        </title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>
            <name>Empire Burlesque 2</name>
        </title>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:call-template name="currentValue" />
        <xsl:call-template name="prevValue" />
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="currentValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="title/name" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="prevValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::title[name][1]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The preceding sibling does not print anything. I want to store both in different variables and compare them. Can you help me pointing what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, when you are checking for the preceding element you are positioned on `cd` element, and that only has other `cd` elements as siblings. Therefore, the expression you want is this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::cd[1]/title/name" />
```